# OMNET++: Enter_Method() from module

Tags: methods, module, omnet++

Currently, I am working and learning about Omnet++. I have two small questions about declaring methods in a module:

1. There is a line: `Enter_Method("indicate")` and `Enter_Method("trigger")` in two different functions in a service-definition (.cc) file. In a general sense, what do they mean?
2. I suppose that there are a list of standard method names (trigger, indicate, etc.) that I can attach my function to those names as methods (I haven't found any information about this). Or there is no such list and I have to regulate the execution time of my own function with a name (by using Enter_Method) in somewhere that I couldn't find.

I suppose the initialize() and handleMessage() are among standard methods.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think I ask the question wrongly. My point is that in a pair of service files (.cc and .h), how can I know when each function is called? in other words, if I define some functions as a method, how can I know when that one is called/used?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest reading the manual regarding the `Enter_Method` call. The string parameter is just a string used in logging function. It has absolutely no meaning to the simulation kernel.

> The second issue is how to let the simulation kernel know that a
> method call across modules is taking place. Why is this necessary in
> the first place? First, the simulation kernel always has to know which
> module's code is currently executing, in order for ownership handling
> and other internal mechanisms to work correctly. Second, the Qtenv
> simulation GUI can animate method calls, but to be able to do that, it
> needs to know about them. Third, method calls are also recorded in the
> event log.

Regarding on the timing of standard callback methods: Please read the manual because that discusses all the supported callback methods.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. I did read the manual about Enter_Method and then I realized I asked the question wrongly. I commented in my post that my point is to figure out when the function (mostly with Enter_Method) is called. In other words, a function when defined must be should be used/called at somewhere and I am just not clear about that.

Comment: Whether a method is called by the simulation kernel (callback) or can be called by the user (normal API call) is absolutely independent of the fact that the method contains an `Enter_Method()` macro. `EnterMethod()` is usually placed into a method that is written by the user and called by user code so, if you see somewhere an EnterMethod() calls, you can be fairly sure that that method is called from the model code somewhere.

Comment: Hello, after finding and reading a bit more, I can understand the meaning of those method now. Thank you for your guidance.